# Migrating DNS Service for an Existing Domain to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have subscribed DNS service at a third party provider and I attached my domain name to my EC2 instance at AWS.
I have successfully migrated the domain name.
But mail has some problem.
They asked me to create a zone file record mail.domainname.com pointing it to their IP Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

So what I did was, I created a record set at Route53 as

Name: mail.domainname.com.
Type: MX-mail exchange
Alias: No
TTL: 300
Value: 10 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

The record set was created.
But mail service is not still working yet.
Is that what I did correct?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
domainname.com.       MX    10   mail.domainname.com
mail.domainname.com   A          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Creation of zone file at AWS for mail server has two steps.

First step:

```
Create record set with ipv4
==========
Name : mail.domain.com
Type: A- IPv4 address
TTL: 3600
Value: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
==========
```

Once this is done, you then need to update the MX record of the 'domain.com' domain as mail.domain.com using the parameter below.

```
==========
Name : domain.com (Or you may leave this blank)
Type: MX- Mail exchange
TTL: 3600
Value: 0 or 10 or 20 mail.domain.com
==========
```

Priority can be upto your DNS provider's assignment.